# My icon gallery addon is crashing Blender after saving the file and restarting. Why?

Tags: python, add-on

I have created an addon where I made an *icon gallery* which appends simple objects and shows the object's properties such as *location*, *rotation mode*, *rotation*, *scale*.

After appending objects to the scene through the addon and saving the file if we again start that blend file the file crashes without opening.

Here is the addon:
https://mega.nz/file/0w8QlZwR#nm_geLuv8YvHuO_w14it1U2LNsKu3jpO_eJc2DwIizk

Here is the code:

````
bl_info = {
    "name": "Icon Gallery Manual",
    "author": "Muzammil",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Icon Gallery",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "View 3D",
}
import bpy, os, bpy.utils.previews
addon_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
files_path = os.path.join(addon_path, 'Blend files')
icons_path = os.path.join(addon_path, 'Images')

wm = bpy.context.window_manager

def dynamic_enum(self,context):
    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    pcoll = previews['main']

    icon_images = []
    for fn in os.listdir(icons_path):
        icon_images.append(fn)

    for i, name in enumerate(icon_images):
        filepath = os.path.join(icons_path, name)
        icon = pcoll.get(name)
        if not icon:
            thumb = pcoll.load(name,filepath, 'IMAGE')
        else:
            thumb = pcoll[name]
        enum_items.append((name,name,'',thumb.icon_id,i))
        
    pcoll.icon_gallery = enum_items
    return pcoll.icon_gallery
    
class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'Icon Gallery'
    bl_idname = 'CUSTOM_PT_PANEL'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Icon Gallery'
    
    def draw(self,context):
        l = self.layout
        l.template_icon_view(wm, 'icon_gallery')
        r = l.row()
        r.scale_y = 2
        r.operator('custom.add_objects', icon = 'HEART')
        c = l.column(align=True)
        if context.object:
            b = c.box()
            b.label(text='Acitve Object: '+context.object.name)
            c.prop(context.object,'location')
            if not bpy.context.object.rotation_mode == 'QUATERNION':
                c.prop(context.object,'rotation_euler', text='Rotation')
            else:
                c.prop(context.object,'rotation_quaternion', text='Rotation')
            c.prop(context.object,'rotation_mode')
            c.prop(context.object,'scale')
        
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = 'Add'
    bl_idname = 'custom.add_objects'
    
    def execute(self,context):
        name = wm.icon_gallery.replace(os.path.splitext(wm.icon_gallery)[1], '')
        before_data = list(bpy.data.objects)
        bpy.ops.wm.append(directory=os.path.join(files_path, 'File.blend','Object'), filename=name)
        new_data = list(filter(lambda d: not d in before_data, list(bpy.data.objects)))
        appended = new_data[0]
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = appended
        appended.location.xyz = (0,0,0)
        appended.rotation_euler.x = 0
        appended.rotation_euler.y = 0
        appended.rotation_euler.z = 0
        appended.scale.xyz = (1,1,1)
        return {'FINISHED'}
classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR]
previews = {}

def register():
    bpy.types.WindowManager.icon_gallery = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=dynamic_enum)
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    pcoll.icon_gallery = ()
    previews['main'] = pcoll
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.icon_gallery
    
    for pcoll in previews.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    previews.clear()

    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining your `wm` variable as global, I'm not 100% sure why but I can only assume this is using the wrong context when reloaded.

Placing the `wm` definition inside the function that is using it solves this as it will use the context passed to it.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Icon Gallery Manual",
    "author": "Muzammil",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Icon Gallery",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "View 3D",
}
import bpy, os, bpy.utils.previews

addon_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
files_path = os.path.join(addon_path, "Blend files")
icons_path = os.path.join(addon_path, "Images")



def dynamic_enum(self, context):
    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    pcoll = previews["main"]

    icon_images = []
    for fn in os.listdir(icons_path):
        icon_images.append(fn)

    for i, name in enumerate(icon_images):
        filepath = os.path.join(icons_path, name)
        icon = pcoll.get(name)
        if not icon:
            thumb = pcoll.load(name, filepath, "IMAGE")
        else:
            thumb = pcoll[name]
        enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    pcoll.icon_gallery = enum_items
    return pcoll.icon_gallery


class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Icon Gallery"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Icon Gallery"

    def draw(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager # moved to here
        l = self.layout
        l.template_icon_view(wm, "icon_gallery")
        r = l.row()
        r.scale_y = 2
        r.operator("custom.add_objects", icon="HEART")
        c = l.column(align=True)
        if context.object:
            b = c.box()
            b.label(text="Acitve Object: " + context.object.name)
            c.prop(context.object, "location")
            if not bpy.context.object.rotation_mode == "QUATERNION":
                c.prop(context.object, "rotation_euler", text="Rotation")
            else:
                c.prop(context.object, "rotation_quaternion", text="Rotation")
            c.prop(context.object, "rotation_mode")
            c.prop(context.object, "scale")


class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add"
    bl_idname = "custom.add_objects"

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager # moved to here
        name = wm.icon_gallery.replace(os.path.splitext(wm.icon_gallery)[1], "")
        before_data = list(bpy.data.objects)
        bpy.ops.wm.append(directory=os.path.join(files_path, "File.blend", "Object"), filename=name)
        new_data = list(filter(lambda d: not d in before_data, list(bpy.data.objects)))
        appended = new_data[0]
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = appended
        appended.location.xyz = (0, 0, 0)
        appended.rotation_euler.x = 0
        appended.rotation_euler.y = 0
        appended.rotation_euler.z = 0
        appended.scale.xyz = (1, 1, 1)
        return {"FINISHED"}


classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL, CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR]
previews = {}


def register():
    bpy.types.WindowManager.icon_gallery = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=dynamic_enum)
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    pcoll.icon_gallery = ()
    previews["main"] = pcoll

    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.icon_gallery

    for pcoll in previews.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    previews.clear()

    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     register()
```

Comment: Thank you. It really helped.